# How could I generate this figure by using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I want generate the following figure (Page 6 in https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/150.pdf).

[image]

I think this figure is generated by using Tikz or Table.

However, I have no any idea to generate it.

Does anyone know how to obtain it?

Thanks.

Comment: I would use a table for this

Comment: Thanks. But the figure 2 of the paper. It is a figure, instead of a table. So, it may be generated by tikz?

Comment: Inside a figure environment, you can put whatever you want. I don't see why one should use a hammersledge like TiKZ for this table-figure.

Comment: Thanks! I don’t know table can be put in the figure. I will try it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Here's how to do it with a `tabular` placed inside a `figure` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % For \coloneqq :=
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}  % Increase spacing between rows by 1.4
\newcommand{\lineNumber}[1]{{\scriptsize \textit{#1}}}  % For consistently typesetting the line numbers
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \fbox{
        \begin{tabular}{p{5.5cm}ll}
             \(\mathsf{aWitExt}_{\mathcal{A},\mathsf{aSIG_{R,SIG}}}(n)\) & \(\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{S}}(m)\) & \(\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{pS}}(m, Y)\)\\\hline
             \lineNumber{1} : \(\mathcal{Q} \coloneqq \emptyset, (sk, pk) \leftarrow \mathsf{Gen}(1^n)\) & \lineNumber{1} : \(\sigma \leftarrow \mathsf{Sign}_{sk}(m)\) & \lineNumber{1} : \(\tilde{\sigma} \leftarrow \mathsf{pSign}_{sk}(m, Y)\)\\
             \lineNumber{2} : \((m^*, Y^*) \leftarrow \mathcal{A}^{\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{S}}, \mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{pS}}}(pk)\) & \lineNumber{2} : \(\mathcal{Q} \coloneqq \mathcal{Q} \cup \{m\}\) & \lineNumber{2} : \(\mathcal{Q} \coloneqq \mathcal{Q} \cup \{m\}\)\\
             \lineNumber{3} : \(\tilde{\sigma} \leftarrow \mathsf{pSign}_{sk}(m^*, Y^*)\) & \lineNumber{3} : \textbf{return} \(\sigma\) & \lineNumber{3} : \textbf{return} \(\tilde{\sigma}\)\\
             \lineNumber{4} : \(\sigma^* \leftarrow \mathcal{A}^{\mathcal{O}_S, \mathcal{O}_{pS}}(\tilde{\sigma})\) & & \\
             \lineNumber{5} : \(y \coloneqq \mathsf{Ext}_{pk}(\sigma^*, \tilde{\sigma}, Y^*)\) & & \\
             \multicolumn{2}{l}{\lineNumber{6} : \textbf{return} \((m^* \notin \mathcal{Q} \wedge (Y^*, y) \notin \mathsf{R} \wedge \mathsf{Vrfy}_{pk}(m^*; \sigma^*))\)} &
        \end{tabular}
        }
        \caption{Caption}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Regarding your statement "Using multicol for the last line spanning multiple columns": The `multicol` package is not related to the `\multicolumn` command.

Comment: Good point, I've removed it, I'd always just assumed it was.

Comment: Thank for your solution!